# Internet issues with Ubuntu in oracle virtual box

Tags: command-line, updates, virtualbox, firefox, internet

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed in as a VM in Oracle virtual box. I am able to browse from firefox but trying to connect from command prompt to update is failing. I also tried to change software sources but even then it is erroring out. The error is "Please check your Internet Connection".

PS : I am using NAT for networking.

What might be is issue and how to correct it?

Comment: what kind of network connection setting has your virtual machine (NAT, Host-Only, ...)?

Comment: Run `software-center` from a terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: @WolfgangVogl  I am using NAT.

Comment: Use Bridged and see if that solves your problem!

Comment: hmmpf, while i used NAT i never had such an problem. My current configuration with a 12.04LTS as virtual machine (13.1 is my host) is to have adapter1 as NAT and adapter2 as host-only - for apt is use a proxy setting to use my host machine. On the host machine i'm running apt-cache-ng (my setup isn't this because it won't work, i just wanted to have my package in a comfortable cache...). But maybe THIS helps you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143776/no-internet-connectivity-in-virtual-box-with-both-host-and-virtual-os-being-12-0?rq=1 - it tells you to set the hardware to AMD PCNet FAST III..

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default network type it's NAT.  To keep NAT, you have to set up port forwarding like [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward).  If you want to act more like a regular computer connected to your network, you want bridged like [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged).

The most common configuration for direct host to guest connectivity and internet connectivity is one host-only and one NAT interface.

My preferred configuration is bridged and host only, so I can access the machine directly and other machines on the network can access it if need be.